# Volume of subgroups and coset decompositions

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, matrix-decomposition

Let $F$ be a number field, $\mathfrak{o}$ be its ring of integers and $\mathfrak{p}$ be the associated maximal ideal. Consider the subgroup $H$ of ${GL}(3, \mathfrak{o})$ given by matrices of the forms
$$\left(\matrix{
\mathfrak{o} & \mathfrak{o} & \mathfrak{o} \\
\mathfrak{p} & \mathfrak{o} & \mathfrak{o} \\
\mathfrak{p} & \mathfrak{p} & \mathfrak{o}
}\right)$$

> What is the index of $H$ in $GL(3, \mathfrak{o})$?

I often face this kind of questions and the answers always appear to be essentially ad hoc treatment of the specific case we are interested in. The only way I see is to compute explicitly the quotient, that is to say to find the explicit decomposition of $GL(3, \mathfrak{o})$ in left (or right) $H$-classes. Is there an algorithmic or systematic way to do so?